# idxmax() not working on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which I created after reading a csv file.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ITC)
print(df.tail(5))
```

This prints

```
            date            open  ...             low           close
488  22-May-2020          188.00  ...          184.60          186.35
489  26-May-2020          190.00  ...          187.80          191.70
490  27-May-2020          192.50  ...          186.90          192.15
491  28-May-2020          192.30  ...          189.00          190.65
492  29-May-2020          190.45  ...          189.00          197.35
```

I wanted to find max from the 'close' column and `df.tail(5).close.max()` works fine.
At last I wanted to print the index of the max value which is 492 so I tried the following

```
print(df.tail(5).close.idxmax())
```

but it gives me the following error

> TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Any idea on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `close` column is not numeric, but filled by strings repr od numbers.

So use:

```
df.close = df.close.astype(float)
```

Or:

```
df.close = pd.to_numeric(df.close, errors='coerce')
```